# How to match the first string in regex, and then run another recursive pattern in regex?

Tags: php, regex, recursion, nested

The regex expression doesn't capture the last closing bracket and stops at the first closing bracket.

Running the regex expression:

```
@media.*(\{([^{}]|(?R))*\})
```

Does not capture get the second bracket.

```
@media screen and (min-width:750px){h1{font-size:2.5em}
  test
 } //doesn't capture
}
```

Feel free to try it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/lF0fI1/457

I'm trying to match the first @media string, continue on until it reaches the first bracket or '{', then run the recursive expression to capture the nested brackets.

Comment: This isnt related to css

Comment: You can use + for one or more }. `@media.*(\{([^{}]|(?R))*\}+)`

Comment: I suspect `@media[^{}]*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*\})` will do what you need.

Comment: I tried that pattern out @WiktorStribiżew and it's pretty efficient, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem one is

```
@media.*
```

`.*` is greedy by nature, So it matches as much as possible you need to make it lazy by adding `?` or using `[^\{]*`

Second is you should be using [`numbered recursive regex`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) `(?1)`  because `(?R)` repeats the complete expression but you need a sub pattern to be repeated

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/lF0fI1/458)